# Core Data removeObject on many-to-many results in object being set to null

Tags: ios, core-data, many-to-many

I have two objects Contact and DealContact with a to-many and inverse relationship set. I have  Core Data generated accessors on DealContact called **removeContactsObject**. DealContact has a relationship to-many to Contact called contacts. When I do this:

```
[dealContact removeContactsObject:oneContact];
```

it results in dealContact object becoming null before I can save or perform any other operation. I've also attempted the following:

```
NSSet *contactSet = [dealContact mutableSetValueForKey:@"contacts"];
[contactSet removeObject:oneContact];
[dealContact setContacts:contactSet];
```

with no success. The dealContact object becomes null after either operation. How can I remove a contact object from the relationship (not delete).

Comment: Are you working on mac osx or ios? (Adding either tag is much more likely to get visibility for your question).

Comment: Working on iOS. Thx for suggestion about tag but how do I add them? I don't see a edit question anywhere.

Comment: Added it for you :)  In the future, there is an 'edit' button right below the tags on the question.  You can click that to edit your tags.  Hope someone can help you!

Comment: Are you using ARC or manually retaining and releasing?  If it's the latter case you may need to send a `retain` message before you remove it otherwise nothing is holding onto it after the remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are not using ARC.  You may simply need to send a `retain` message to the contact object before removing it.  When the object is removed from the set it will be released, the managedObjectContext does not retain it's registered objects by default so the set may be the only object holding on to it. e.g.

```
[dealContact retain];
[dealContact removeContactsObject:oneContact];
//.... add to new relationship
[dealContact release];
```

Comment: I tried this without success. I do not want to release the dealContact object. I'm deleting oneContact from dealContact and thus only altering the set that holds the contacts.

Comment: It was not an issue of retain but rather I was not passing along the dealContact object to another screen where the removeContactsObject call was being run. Thanks for the pointers.